seekbar library giving issue while syncing
implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2'

while implementing the library giving this issue.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
I tried degrading and upgrading the gradle versions.
Cache removed and newly built the project. Tried almost all the existing approaches.

Please, Check the issues. version 2.1.2 is available but has not been released yet. Here is the Library Issue page. Currently, the issue is open. That's the reason behind it.

Downgrade the version to v2.1.1
implementation 'com.github.warkiz:IndicatorSeekBar:v2.1.1'

It's the same for previous versions.

I got the same answer from the GitHub issue page. check this. this comment was posted 2 weeks ago and it's working well.

issue fixed thanks!!!

Since JCenter shut down on August 15, 2024, the library 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2' that relies on JCenter is now unavailable.
Here are possible solutions:
Find an Alternative: Search for a similar Seekbar library available on Maven Central, which can be used instead of the old one.
AAR File: If you have access to an older build PC or can locate the AAR file for indicatorseekbar:2.1.2 from the internet, you can load the AAR file directly into your project via Gradle.
